# "With whom ...?" vs. "Whom .... with?"

Tags: prepositions, whom

Which one of these questions is correct or both?

**A**

> With whom do you watch movies?

**B**

> Whom do you watch movies with?

Answer (score 5):

> 1. With whom do you watch movies?
> 2. Whom do you watch movies with?

Both of these sentences are grammatical. You can either move the interrogative word *who(m)* to the beginning of the sentence as in (2), or you can move the whole preposition phrase containing the interrogative word to the beginning as in (1).

Fronting the whole preposition phrase gives the sentence a formal and literary effect. Probably not what you're after for this sentence which doesn't seem to have a very formal topic. If you are aiming at colloquial speech you probably want to leave the preposition at the end of the sentence.

However, if you do leave the preposition at the end of the sentence, you do not need the rather formal (and some might even think haughty) *whom*. It is far more common even in formal situations to use *who* in such sentences. That would give you example 3:

3. Who do you watch movies with?

In contrast, if the whole preposition phrase is fronted, you must use *whom* and *who* would be ungrammatical as shown in (4):

4. *With who do you watch movies? (ungrammatical)

Comment: @janus Bahs Jacquet Thanks for catching that!  [This is also a test comment regarding this query here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10206/commenting-to-editors)

Comment: It seems to work!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah! That's good :)

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

Another example:
To whom would you like to talk?
Whom would you like to talk to？

Answer (score 0):

Words like *with*, *for*, *at*, *to*, *in* etc., are called ***pre*positions**. As the name suggests, they are put before the words with which they are linked: ***in* the street**, etc.

In English, however, most prepositions are in fact, functionally speaking, ***post*positions**. Hence you have two equally correct patterns:

> 1. Preposition + linked word [usually article + noun] + the rest of the sentence.

>

> 2. Linked word [usually article + noun] + the rest of the sentence + preposition (used postpositionally).

Comment: No, most prepositions in English are prepositions. Stranded prepositions appearing after their object are not nearly as common as prepositions in their canonical place before their object.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, you have totally misunderstood my comment. No problem.

Comment: Then you should clarify. The only difference between a preposition and a postposition is whether it precedes or follows its object; there is no other difference. If you weren’t claiming that most prepositions in English come after their object (which they don’t), then you should rephrase to make it clearer what you did mean.